# monaco-editor - resize property causes editor popups to be hidden

Tags: html, css, monaco-editor

I am using `deltaDecorations` to show errors in my editor. 
here is my code: https://gist.github.com/dinager/41578bd658b60cc912a6023f80431810 
Here is the result:

[image]

I am trying to add resize property to the editor by adding to the style

```
resize: both;overflow: auto;
```

But then the hover message is partly hidden by the edges of the editor 
As you can see in below attached image - the editor can resize now (bottom right), but the hover message is partly hidden

[image]

How can I add resize property to not hide elements? 
Another question: can I make the hover message float inside the editor, meaning if it's at the top line it should float to the bottom, if at the side of the editor float to the middle, etc..

Attaching the code adding the `markerDecorations` (exists also in the gist link at the top):

```
  this.markerDecorations = codeEditor.deltaDecorations(this.markerDecorations, [
    {
      range: new monaco.Range(pos.startLine, pos.startColumn, pos.endLine, pos.endColumn),
      options: {
        className: 'squiggly-error',
        minimap: {
          color: { id: 'minimap.errorHighlight' },
          position: monaco.editor.MinimapPosition.Gutter,
        },
        overviewRuler: {
          color: { id: 'editorOverviewRuler.errorForeground' },
          position: monaco.editor.OverviewRulerLane.Full,
        },
        stickiness: monaco.editor.TrackedRangeStickiness.AlwaysGrowsWhenTypingAtEdges,
        zIndex: 1,
        hoverMessage: { value: parseResponse.error, isTrusted: false },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding `fixedOverflowWidgets: true` on `monaco.editor.create` options.

```
this.editor = monaco.editor.create(el, {
    // ...
    fixedOverflowWidgets: true

});
```